# How to get boolean values as output on a list for a python list containing Boolean values

Tags: python, boolean

I have 3 Lists as below

```
enter code here

A = [True, True, True]

B = [True, True, True,True,True,True]

C = [True, False, True, True]
```

From the above lists i need to get output for each list as True if all the elements in the list are True else False
Required Output 
   [True,True,False]

Comment: check [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function

Comment: please add your code, showcasing what you have tried

Answer (score 3):

[`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) does exactly this (Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty)):

```
print([all(A), all(B), all(C)])
```

Comment: Thank you ..@fferri

Answer (score 0):

See the functions [all()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all) and [any()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any).

```
>>> lst = [True, False]
>>> any(lst)
True
>>> all(lst)
False
```

As you can see you want the "`any()`" function.